# При нажатии кнопки "Назад" в главном Activity кнопки перестают работать

Tags: android, activity

Имеется приложение с двумя активити. При переходе из главного активити во второе активити и последующем нажатии аппаратной кнопки "Назад", возврат в главное активити происходит, но кнопки в нем становятся неактивными, то есть нельзя снова перейти во второе активити по той же кнопке. На сколько я понимаю, при переходе в второе акт-ти, главное не убивается, а просто остается невидимым и при возвращении в него кнопки, созданные в `onCreate()` должны остаться не изменны. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упустил?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView myTextView;
    Button btnSmrt;
    Button btnTl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sde);

        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        myTextView.setText("....");

        btnSmrt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnTl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btnSmrt.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTl.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                myTextView.setText("...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Активити, находящееся на заднем плане может быть убито системой в случае нехватки памяти. Что значит кнопки становятся неактивны? Они  выглядят будто `enabled == false` или просто не реагируют на нажатия? Также добавьте в вопрос код активити.

Comment: Если бы оно было убито, меня бы выкидывало из приложения т.к. это мэйн активити (в корне таска), и если оно убито, то активти в таске не останется. Кнопки не реагируют на нажатие, выглядят они также.

Comment: Может InstantRun чудит? Попробуйте удалить приложение с устройства и пересобрать проект.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Еще уточню, второе активити в onCreate запускает AsyncTask, в котором идет обращение к серверу, который получает ответ от БД, и получает ответ от сервера в json формате, парсит его и в onPostExecute передает это в ListView. Может ли быть дело в этом AsyncTask? Код выкладывать не буду, там очень много.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)